# WordPress RSS feed?

Tags: rss, feed

We just started our new blog and we need to submit our RSS feed to some directories, but we do not know what is our new site RSS feed.

Do we need to install any plugin or tool to generate RSS feed?

If feed is already generated by WordPress, where we can find our RSS feed url/link?

This is our website http://www.scoopaper.com/

Comment: https://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_Feeds#Finding_Your_Feed_URL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you check the source of the website, you can see two links (CTRL+U to view source):

```
<link rel="alternate" type="application/rss+xml" title="Scoopaper &raquo; Feed" href="http://www.scoopaper.com/feed/" />
<link rel="alternate" type="application/rss+xml" title="Scoopaper &raquo; Comments Feed" href="http://www.scoopaper.com/comments/feed/" />
```

Which means you have: http://www.scoopaper.com/feed/ and 
http://www.scoopaper.com/comments/feed/ (if comments are open it will display a RSS feed of the comments)

Comment: wow mam thank u so much it helped us a lot i checked the feed it i showing as for comment feed we just disabled wordpress comment thats why it is not showing that but once again thank u